# How to access the instace of class c created in class A from Class B when calss B is called from Class A using instance

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have 3 Classes say Class A and Class B and class C.
My class A is creating an instance of Class B  and class C and is calling class B method and class C method. Now i need to access the class c instance created in class A from class B method without creating the new instance of class C.

```
Class A
{

   B b = new B();
   C c = new C();
   c.MethodC();
   b.MethodB();

}

Class B
{
  MethodB()
  {
    //some functionality implemented
    // Here i need to access instance c created in class A
  }
}

Class C
{
   MethodC()
   {
     // comman logic for validation
   }
}
```

Can anyone help me with the above logic.

Comment: Is adding a parameter of type `C` to `MethodB` possible? You wouldn't normally want different classes "reaching" into each other's internal structures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could ...

Add a parameter of `C` to `MethodB`: (don't, actually but possible)

```
void MethodB(C c){c.MethodC();}
```

which has the downside of introducing a dependency: `B` "knows" of class `C` which is not desirable.

Or add a parameter of `Action` to `MethodB`:

```
void MethodB( Action a ) { a(); }
```

and call that like this:

```
// in a Method in A
b.MethodB(() => c.MethodC());
```

Or you can work with an Interface:

```
public interface ICommonValidationLogic{
    public void Validate();
}

class C : ICommonValidationLogic
{
     public override void Validate(){
           // Do your thing
     }
}

class B
{
    public void MethodB( ICommonValidationLogic v )
    {
         // v here is actually the instance of C created in A
         v.Validate();
    }
}

class A
{
     void SomeMethodOfA()
     {
         B b = new B();
         ICommonValidationLogic c = new C();
         b.MethodB(c);
     }
}
```

Comment: I do not want to create a new instance of A and C in class B.Somehow i need to call back class A and access the instance of class C which i already created in class A

Comment: @PruthviVasist This code above only creates one single B and one single C inside class A. You seem to have a misconception about when an instance of a class is created.

Answer (score 0):

You can return the instance of class that you want to access.